# Side effects of creating top-level class in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, package, naming-conventions

Besides possible class name collisions, would there be any problems with or side effects of creating a top-level (no package name) class with a name like "Tracer" in ActionScript 3?  I want to keep such a class top-level so I don't have to use import statements for it in my code.  So far I haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use a package whenever appropriate. If what you're building is a utility, it's better to put it in a `util` package than leave it top level.

If you're developing something that could be seen as **core functionality**, there's no issue in implementing a **top-level** member.

The last thing to plan for is **reusability**. If you know you're building something that you're never going to reuse (final implementation classes), don't worry too much about having it be a top-level class as it should continue to work once you've compiled the swf.

If, instead, you're making a feature that you'd like to reuse as a **framework**, you're probably better off putting it as a **framework-level** member for flexibility with future development.

Comment: Thanks.  Tracer replaces trace command. Tracer traces, reroutes, logs, and dispatches events for calls to Tracer.write(...args) and Tracer.writeError(e:Error).  It's part of a framework (a flash-based OS [shell/gui/dock-controls/net-transaction,etc.]), compiled into a reusable SWC.  Tracer is a special case, because it could be used anywhere transiently, so I think it makes sense as a top-level class that doesn't need an import statement.  I posted implementation of Tracer here if interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715738/creating-a-custom-trace-class-in-as3/4453850#4453850

Comment: Marked Answer: "...there's no issue in implementing a top-level member." [other than the possible name collisions as I mentioned]

Answer (score 2):

zzzzBov's answer is good advice. But to answer your question explicitly: possible name collisions are indeed the only side effect to what you're doing.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the explicit answer.  Other answer says there's no [other] issues too, but with a conditional tone.  This is good to know.  Love your Gecko btw!

Answer (score 1):

I'm about to describe a possible issue I thought of, and I'm posting it because it's not technically a name collision (the letter-case is different).

Suppose you have a top-level class that shares the name of a top-level package aside from a difference in letter-case (for example "flash", "fl", "com", or a custom package).  If you type something like "var x:" and then try to type a fully qualified classname... then the code-completion engine in a program like FlashDevelop will default to your "Flash" class (if it exists), rather than the "flash" package you may be trying to type.  It's extremely irritating, mainly because it makes a little bit of sense that it functions that way, and it kinda has to code-complete one or the other :(

So be very careful naming top-level classes something that's spelled the same as a package name (top-level or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

I had a class named Vector in a custom package and using flash 9 and everything worked perfect until I had to use flash 10 to save files the problem was that I wasn't able to create an instance of my class Vector due with error TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor. The only way to fix it was changing the name of the AS class, fortunately the binding for backend class works with my Java's class Vector.

Seems that flash isn't taking care of class package for top level classes.

I hope this helps somebody, even when the date of this question is almost 2 years ago.